# like button is not showing real amount

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I just embedded like button on my business page the wax cabana, but it is not showing the real amount that I see on my page. Why?  How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

> **What makes up the number shown on my Like button?**
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> 1. The number of likes of this URL
> 2. The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook).
> 3. The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
> 4. The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL

So the Like button does not include only likes, but other things too.